# Nicely formatting file creation date

Tags: linux, bash, date, format

I would like to use the nice formatting facilities that I find in the "date" command to format a file creation date. But I can't find any way to get output from "stat" that "date -d" will accept. Is there any way to do what I want within bash, or am I going to have to write C code?

What I tried:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ stat --format %y foo.txt
2022-02-24 11:54:25.619999973 -0500
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ stat --format %Y foo.txt
1645721665
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ date -d `stat --format %Y foo.txt`
date: invalid date ‘1645721665’
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ date -d `stat --format %y foo.txt`
date: invalid option -- '0'
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

What I would really like is to build a filename, using creation date as input:

```
% echo "$(date +"%y%m%d_%H%M").log"
220318_0955.log
```

Comment: please update the question with a sample of your `stat` output, the desired creation date and the expected/final results (I'm assuming you want to use something like `touch` to modify the file's create/birth date?)

Answer (score 2):

try this
date +"%y%m%d_%H%M" -d "@$(stat --format %Y foo.txt)"

Comment: This doesn't work on all platforms (try it on OSX - date isn't GNU date there), and your answer could use some formatting improvements (like putting the code into code format)

Answer (score 0):

With GNU [stat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) if your underlying filesystem support the `birth` time these formatting options can be rolled to give you what you want:

> %w     time of file birth, human-readable; - if unknown
>
> %W     time of file birth, seconds since Epoch; 0 if unknown

**Please** don't confuse a creation date (better known as the birth date) with the `ctime` or last status change time of a file!